# Insert new three new keys in array multidimensional

Tags: php

I have a query that will bring columns in different number. 
Below my query brought two lines only but could be four, five or more. 
But for each new array I need to insert three different keys (column_4, column_5, and column_6).

I am trying to the code below but it will sum just the columns with the same key and it is  not what I want to have:

```
$result = array();

foreach($arr[0] as $k => $v)
$result[$k] = array_sum(array_column($arr, $k));
```

I have the array below:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(9) {
    ["column_1"]=>
    string(15) "Primary"
    ["column_2"]=>
    string(6) "298.50"
    ["column_3"]=>
    string(6) "298.50"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(9) {
    ["column_1"]=>
    string(17) "Secondary"
    ["column_2"]=>
    string(6) "694.50"
    ["column_3"]=>
    string(6) "694.50"
  }
}
```

And I want this final result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(9) {
    ["column_1"]=>
    string(15) "Primary"
    ["column_2"]=>
    string(6) "298.50"
    ["column_3"]=>
    string(6) "298.50"
    ["column_4"]=>
    string(6) "298.50"
    ["column_5"]=>
    string(6) "299.50"
    ["column_6"]=>
    string(6) "300.50"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(9) {
    ["column_1"]=>
    string(17) "Secondary"
    ["column_2"]=>
    string(6) "694.50"
    ["column_3"]=>
    string(6) "694.50"
    ["column_4"]=>
    string(6) "694.50"
    ["column_5"]=>
    string(6) "695.50"
    ["column_6"]=>
    string(6) "696.50"
  }
}
```

Where the information in the columns will be as show below:

```
column_4: Average;
column_5: Average + 1
column_6: Average + 2
```

Comment: How the heck did you get `1,389` for column_4 when the previous two are `694.50`??

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I just fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop `$result` and perform calculations on it's members by adding to that position's array members:

```
foreach( $result as $k => $v )
{
    $result[ $k ][ 'column_4' ] = ( $v[ 'column_2' ] + $v[ 'column_3' ] ) / 2;
    $result[ $k ][ 'column_5' ] = $result[ $k ][ 'column_4' ] + 1;

    // I will let you figure out column_6 for yourself :)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Using your concept I was able to reach a solution.

Answer (score 1):

if you're trying to do this inside a query you can do this

```
SELECT AVG(my_column_name) as column_4, 
    AVG(my_column_name) + 1 as column_5,
    AVG(my_column_name) +2 as column_6
    FROM tablename
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I need to do it trough PHP.

Comment: No problem.  Does the answer from MonkeyZeus work for you?